# How to start python in "-X dev" mode when debugging / running from terminal?

Tags: python, debugging, visual-studio-code

python3 supports `-X dev` startup mode.

This feature is becoming very useful  for code "environment awareness" and for execution functionality.

For ex. the debug prints of asyncio module https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-dev.html#debug-mode-of-asyncio

How can I configure vscode to start python with this flag ?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'd love to know the answer if so

Answer (score 1):

vscode now supports `pythonArgs` in `launch.json`, but note that it expects a format of `['-X', 'dev']`:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "pythonArgs": ["-X", "dev"],
        },
    ]
}
```